# Excluindo arquivos no Github depois do push

Tags: git, github

Criei meu primeiro repositório para estudar sobre git e github, fiz meus primeiros commits e pushs no repositório remoto e só depois me dei conta de que upei um arquivo que não queria, como faço para retirá-lo do repositório no github? 
OBS: Já coloquei esse arquivo o .gitignore e mesmo assim o arquivo não é excluído do repositório remoto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No terminal, dentro da pasta do seu projeto, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
git init
git rm --cached NOME_DO_ARQUIVO
git commit -m "Apagar arquivo"
git push origin master
```

Comment: A resposta foi editada para excluir apenas do Github

Answer (score 3):

Faça o seguinte:

1. Comente a linha do arquivo no `.gitignore`
2. Remova ele do diretório local, copie para uma outra pasta
3. Atualize o índice -> `git add`
4. Realize o `commit`
5. Realize o `push` para o repositório remoto
6. Remova o comentário da linha do arquivo no `.gitignore`
7. Copie ele novamente para o diretório local

Answer (score 2):

Um forma simples de remover um arquivo de um repositório no GITHUB é pela própria interface WEB do github.

Basta acessar o arquivo que se quer apagar e clicar no **botão excluir**, ele parece uma lixeira no **canto superior direito da tela**.